# Як перекласти з російської "выходить" у значенні "мати успіх у виконанні якогось завдання"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як перекласти з російської "выходить" у значенні "мати успіх у виконанні якогось завдання"? Наприклад, "у меня всё вышло".

I hope this is not too broad. Here is a research effort:

[https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=выходить&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)
[https://ru.glosbe.com/ru/uk/выходить](https://ru.glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)
[https://gufo.me/dict/ruuk/выходить](https://gufo.me/dict/ruuk/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: «Мені [вдалося](http://sum.in.ua/s/udavatysja)»? Та й навіть «у мене вийшло» можна (14-те значення [тут](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=11534&page=384); хоч мені якось не дуже звучить).

Comment: Хіба 14? "(14) Вихо́дити (става́ти) / ви́йти (ста́ти) на старт: а) займати вихідне положення перед початком змагання з подолання якої-небудь відстані."

Comment: «14. Утворюватися, удаватися яким-небудь унаслідок певної дії… // тільки док. Стати ким-небудь або подібним до когось, набути певних рис, якостей і т. ін… // Траплятися… // Ставати розв'язаним, завершеним і т. ін… // Закінчуватися, складатися певним чином…»

Comment: Тоді, мабуть, доцільніше було б сформулювати початкове запитання як "Чи можна так сказати українською?" Хоча це вже наступним разом. Однаково я хочу побачити усе розмаїття варіантів (впевнений, комусь це теж може бути цікаво).

Comment: Ще раз: research effort — це не для jury. Це для вас. Це ви хочете отримати відповідь, і це ви формулюєте запитання так, щоб воно було а) зрозумілим; б) обмеженим, аби потенційні автори відповідей **не гаяли даремно свій час** і не вгадували, чого хотів автор запитання.

Comment: Уже зрозуміле та обмежене? Це добре. Що незрозуміло або не обмежено у моєму попередньому запитанні?

https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5919/%d0%af%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%96%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%be%d1%97?noredirect=1#comment9463_5919

Answer (score 4):

> Вышло

це частина фразеологізму. Тобто можна підібрати будь-яку вдалу альтернативу, або використати те саме слово, якщо розумієте значення.

Дубровський. Московсько-українська фразеологія. 1917.

> Вышло по моему, какъ я говорилъ - На моє слово впало. На моє вийшло.

Завдання: рішилося, вдалося, далося, виконалося, вийшло, отрималося. В залежності від того що саме потрібно сказати чи донести до слухача. Хто як каже.

Comment: "Тобі вдалося?" "Мені все вдалося". Гарно.